# Cant get rid of grey colour behind TabBar in Swift

Tags: swift, view, uitabbarcontroller, uicolor, tabbar

I put a background image to my view, so the full view should have it.

```
let background = UIImage(named: "background")
var imageView : UIImageView!
imageView = UIImageView(frame: view.bounds)
imageView.contentMode =  UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFill
imageView.clipsToBounds = true
imageView.image = background
imageView.center = view.center
view.addSubview(imageView)
self.view.sendSubviewToBack(imageView)
```

Also I have a barTintColor for my tabBar:

```
tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blue
```

The problem is when my TabBar is transparent for some percent, I can see behind the grey color(probably the default color) instead of my view's background image...

Debug view hierarchy:

[image]

Comment: Can you attach an image of `Debug View Hierarchy` please?

Comment: Thank you, so now you see what grey background you see? Can you try to iterate over `tabBar` subview's and make desire view just transparent or similar color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
UITabBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
```